# Computing the function field of a product of varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The function field of a variety $V = V(I)$ in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ is given by:

$$K_V = \left\{\frac{f}{g}, f,g\in \mathcal{O}(V) : g \notin I\right\}$$

where $\frac{f_1}{f_2} \sim \frac{g_1}{g_2} \iff f_1 g_2 - f_2 g_1 \in I$.

Now suppose $V$ is a variety given by a polynomial $p(x,y,z) = 0$ in the projective plane, then if I form the Cartesian product:

$$V \times \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$$

How do I compute the function field of this variety (since I think the product of two varieties is also a variety)? I'm trying to understand to apply the definition in the case of this cartesian product.